# Deploying telegram bot

Tags: python, deployment, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I have developed a simple telegram bot using the telebot library in python. I want to deploy it somewhere so it's always running, preferably for free. I was thinking vercel, but can't get it to work, what is the easiest way to do this and the best place to deploy? Is there a template that I can use somewhere and then just replace it with my functions etc.?

I tried running it on vercel already and Heroku but it didn't quite work, I am open to using another library if need be, I just have my functions ready and want to make a telegram bot out of them, the current library works locally, but I want to deploy.